# How to solve problems with the function googler?

Tags: r, github, tibble

I tried an example here : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googler/googler.pdf

The answer is an empty tibble... I don't understand why it doesn't work for me...

Code is on github but I don't know exactly how to find where is the problem...

Is there an alternative to the function googler if it still doesn't work?

```
> library(googler)
> googler("rstats", time = "m1")
# A tibble: 0 x 0
```

Comment: I tried again and I received this warning message : ''' "Warning message:
In system2(cmd, args = args, stdout = TRUE) :
  l'exécution de la commande '"\Users\Ludovic\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps/python3.exe" C:\Users\Ludovic\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2bLvDs/googler "rstats" --time m1 -C --json'  renvoie un statut 9009" '''